# Phaser 3 game shirt on the top, pants at the back

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

so I am creating a game using Phaser 3, with a little treat at the end which is to allow people to customize the characters by selecting the outfits that they want. I am able to finish up the customizing, but now I was wondering if it is possible to have the shirt to always be at the top layer, and the pants to be behind the shirt. You are able to select the shirt or pants first, but whatever is selected second would overlap the first like the image below

[image]

I would like for it to be the shirt to always be on top, and the pants to always be below, regardless of whether you select the shirt first or the pants first, like the image below

[image]

The code below is the position and size of the shirt when it is on the mascot

```
const topsImages = [
  {
    costUrl: "U10",
    cost: 1.0,
    src: "SLICES/upperpri/sm1.png",
    x: 91,
    y: 40,
    scaleX: 0.54,
    scaleY: 0.54,
  },
  {
    costUrl: "U20",
    cost: 1.0,
    src: "SLICES/upperpri/smartshirt.png",
    x: 91,
    y: 38,
    scaleX: 0.51,
    scaleY: 0.51,
  },
}
```

The code below is to add the clothing onto the mascot, and the setDepth is me attempting to add overlapping part.

```
tabs.on(
  "button.click",
  function (button, groupName, index) {
    filter = button.text;

    if (this._prevTypeButton) {
      this._prevTypeButton.getElement("background").setTint(0xcfe2f3);
    }
    button.getElement("background").clearTint();
    this._prevTypeButton = button;

    let items = GetImagesForFilter(this._prevTypeButton.text).map(
      (item) => {
        return {
          src: item.src,
          costUrl: item.costUrl,
          cost: item.cost,
          key: this._prevTypeButton.text,
          index,
          x: item.x,
          y: item.y,
          scaleX: item.scaleX,
          scaleY: item.scaleY,
        };
      }
    );
    this.getElement("panel").setItems(items).scrollToTop();
  },
  tabs
);
    this.input.on(Phaser.Input.Events.POINTER_DOWN, function (pointer) {
        pantsImages.setDepth(0);
        topsImages.setDepth(1);
    })
```

Comment: Thankyou for the code,  Just one question, the two variables `pantsImages` and `topsImages`, where are they created/set? are the images, a group, sprites, or ... ? could you add here a bit of context?

Comment: `setDepth`, will only work on phaser gameObjects. `topsImages` is a Array of Javascript Objects. there should be code like `this.add.image`, or `this.add,sprite` or so

Comment: can you share the code where you are adding the images/items to the scene, must be something like `this.add.image`, `this.add.sprite`, or so. that is where the `setDepth` call should be located.

Comment: So I have managed to resolve my issue where I am able to overlap the top using setDepth(). But because of that, I ran into another issue where the button that is used to remove the clothing is not working anymore, specifically removing the top.

Comment: Did you check the browser debug console for errors?

Comment: the error it gave me was that it cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destory') the items are being removed by it being 'destoryed'

Comment: Would it be possible if I send you the javascript file and you just look through it? I think it would be easier to understand the code as there is a lot of code here

Comment: If you can share the code, over some link like: github, jsfiddle, codepen, dropbox, google drive, or so I would look at it.

Comment: https://github.com/Javyers/Phaser-3-FYP-project. This includes the javascript and the html file. If you need me to add other files to see more. Do let me know as well. Thank you

Comment: I updated my answer with a **quick fix** idea (its at the end), I hope it helped

Answer (score 4):

You can use *"depth sorting"* of the gameobjects.

just define with object should be on top, and set it with the  `setDepth` function.:

> **for example:**
>
> - shirts always depth: 2
> - t-shirts always depth: 0 (under the pants)
> - pants always depth: 1
> - hats always depth: 3
> - ...

And than setting it on display or so.

Documentation to Depht/Layers: https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Layer.html

There is a nice example on phaser.io https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/depth-sorting/z-index

**Alternatively**

If all clothes are in a Group/List you could also use the functions `bringToTop`, `moveUp`, `moveDown`, ... to position the piece on the right layer.

```
...
this.currentOutfitGroup.add(shirt);
this.currentOutfitGroup.add(pants);
...
this.currentOutfitGroup.children.bringToTop(shirt);
...
```

like in the example: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/depth-sorting/bring-to-top

**Update**:

Just to clarify: the function `setDepth` should be called on a Phaser gameobject ([link to documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Components.Depth.html))

like in the examples above:

```
let selectedTop = this.add.image(100, 300, 'top_phaser_key');
```

And on this objected that is returned `selectedTop` you can set the depth.

**Information:** calling setDepth on Javascript Object list `topsImages` and `pantsImages` should have throw an error in the browser console. like *"...setDepth is not a function..."*

**Update to Javascript Code from GitHub** *(Jump to **Quick Fix**, if you want only a solution)*:

> Just as an Inf: Your code is really long, It could be optimizied with some Phaser Loader like shown here in this example: https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/loader/file-pack/load-file-pack-from-json

Back to the Problem `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'destroy')`, it is abit difficult to pinpoint, since alot is happening.
Nevertheless:

- at around line 1256 you are calling destroy on `itemToRemove` this object is not set(atleast in my tests)

  - you could do a not null check link in line 1137
- checking the object's the `playerContainer` has a length of one (only the player), because nothing is added.
- checking the add function, I assume starting line 830:

  - no item is being added to the `playerContainer`

    - it seem's that in the if/else statments from line 850 - 1132 you are always exiting so the `playerContainer.add` on line 1159 is not called.

Since I don't exactly know the logic, add it is alot to read, I just can guess, *that you are mixing the logic of showing the clothes with buying them, and if you can't pay for one piece it will not be added to the container, this causes the issue. **(really just guessing)***

**A Quick Fix, could be:**
On line 1254: check `itemToRemove` like:

```
if(!itemToRemove){
    //... hide item 
    reset(filter);
    return;
}
```

It' s not an elegant solution but should work.

You could write a `reset` function like this:

```
function reset(type){
    if(type.toLowerCase() == "top"){
        engineershirttop.setVisible(false);
        smartshirttop.setVisible(false);
        denimshirttop.setVisible(false);
        stripedshirttop.setVisible(false);
        bluecoattop.setVisible(false);
        redcoattop.setVisible(false);
        architecttop.setVisible(false);
        cheftop.setVisible(false);
        firefightertop.setVisible(false);
        medicallabscientisttop.setVisible(false);
        doctortop.setVisible(false);
        lawyertop.setVisible(false);            
    } else if(type.toLowerCase() == "pants"){
        ...
    } ...
}
```

**Extra:** the `reset` function could be use in other parts of your code, like (in the lines 847+):

```
    if (filter == "Top") {
        reset(filter);
        if (costUrl == "U10") {
            engineershirttop.setVisible(true);
            return;
        }else if (costUrl == "U20") {
            smartshirttop.setVisible(true);
        } ...
    ...
```

this could save you some lines of code.

Comment: Can I check, the bigger the number for depth sorting, e.g. shirt is like 2 and pants are 1, it means that the shirt would be on the top?

Comment: When I try to use depth sorting, and go to check on the website, there were no changes, and it tells me that the pantsImages.setDepth and topsImages.setDepth (pantsImages and topsImages are a const that was written to add the pictures to fit on the mascot)

Comment: Yes the bigger number means it will be on top. if you use the same number the drawing order counts.

Comment: @JavierWong did you checkout the example https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/depth-sorting/z-index does the demo work?

Comment: @JavierWong without seeing more code, I can't say what the problem is. Can update your post, some more code _(only relevant parts)_ where your create the items und were you add/position them?

Comment: yes the demo works and I tried it.

Comment: @JavierWong I updated my answer, I hope this clears things up

Comment: If I want to use depth sorting, how can I do so with like many different assets? From what I usually see, people use depth sorting, but its mainly for like 1 or 2 items, and not like for a huge group of assets

Comment: @JavierWong you can use the same Depth for elements on the same level: 'pants-> depth=1' , 'shirts-> depth=2', ... if two assets have the same depth the drawing order is used, but because nobody will _wear_ 2 pants, that should not be a problem.

Comment: @JavierWong I updated my answer, I hope this helps. p.s.: try to reuse code like the "Dont repeat yourself" motto says. this will save you alot of work.