# Phaser 3 trying to overlap assets

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

so I am currently working on a game/quiz using Phaser.io framework. At the end of the quiz, you would have the option to customize the mascot with the attire of your choice. However, at the moment, I am able to select the outfit at any order and they would appear at the top like such.

[image]

I would like to make it such that the top would always be at the top, while the pants would always be beneath the top like such.

[image]

I researched and was told that I could use setDepth() to help me out for this. Unfortunately, I am using multiple different assets, and I saw that setDepth only worked with 1 asset at a time.

// shirt & top

```
this.load.image("sportsattire", "SLICES/lowerpri/12top.png");
this.load.image("sweeperoveralls", "SLICES/lowerpri/11top.png");
this.load.image("bumblebee", "SLICES/lowerpri/7top.png");
this.load.image("schoolshirt", "SLICES/lowerpri/13top.png");
this.load.image("alien", "SLICES/lowerpri/1top.png");
this.load.image("drummajor", "SLICES/lowerpri/10top.png");
this.load.image("pirate", "SLICES/lowerpri/3top.png");
this.load.image("artist", "SLICES/lowerpri/8top.png");
this.load.image("painter", "SLICES/lowerpri/9top.png");
this.load.image("astronaut", "SLICES/upperpri/5top.png");
this.load.image("officeshirt", "SLICES/upperpri/1top.png");
this.load.image("scientist", "SLICES/lowerpri/10top.png");

//pants
this.load.image("sportsshorts", "SLICES/lowerpri/10pants.png");
this.load.image("sweeperpants", "SLICES/lowerpri/8pants.png");
this.load.image("bumblebeepants", "SLICES/lowerpri/2pants.png");
this.load.image("schoolshorts", "SLICES/lowerpri/11pants.png");
this.load.image("alienpants", "SLICES/lowerpri/3pants.png");
this.load.image("drummajorpants", "SLICES/lowerpri/4pants.png");
this.load.image("piratepants", "SLICES/lowerpri/5pants.png");
this.load.image("artistpants", "SLICES/lowerpri/6pants.png");
this.load.image("officepants", "SLICES/lowerpri/9pants.png");
```

The method I am using to add the clothing to the mascot is javascript, which does not allow me to use setDepth().

```
const topsImages = [
  {
    costUrl: "T13",
    cost: 1.0,
    src: "SLICES/lowerpri/12top.png",
    x: 90,
    y: 47,
    scaleX: 0.5,
    scaleY: 0.5,
  },
  {
    costUrl: "T12",
    cost: 1.0,
    src: "SLICES/lowerpri/11top.png",
    x: 90,
    y: 39,
    scaleX: 0.5,
    scaleY: 0.5,
  },
}
```

The code on the top is me storing the data, while the bottom is how it would appear on the mascot.

```
tabs.on(
  "button.click",
  function (button, groupName, index) {
    filter = button.text;

    if (this._prevTypeButton) {
      this._prevTypeButton.getElement("background").setTint(0xcfe2f3);
    }
    button.getElement("background").clearTint();
    this._prevTypeButton = button;

    let items = GetImagesForFilter(this._prevTypeButton.text).map(
      (item) => {
        return {
          src: item.src,
          costUrl: item.costUrl,
          cost: item.cost,
          key: this._prevTypeButton.text,
          index,
          x: item.x,
          y: item.y,
          scaleX: item.scaleX,
          scaleY: item.scaleY,
        };
      }
    );
    this.getElement("panel").setItems(items).scrollToTop();
  },
  tabs
);
```

Is there any way I am able to use setDepth() or other methods to make the top overlap the pants regardless of which button to click?

Comment: You need to set layers over the sprite (possibly with other invisible sprites) and set their view depths. Layer them such that you have the original sprite -> under layer -> over layer

Comment: Is there an example to set the view depth? I am very new to phaser 3 and this was actually a handed down project, whihc is why I have so many changes that I am unsure how to do

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Phaser 3 game shirt on the top, pants at the back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70492447/phaser-3-game-shirt-on-the-top-pants-at-the-back)